# ReentrantLock not giving expected result

Tags: java, concurrency, locking

I have created a producer consumer program using threads (wait and notify) feature. The code is -

```
/**
 *  Message.java ( Common object )
 */
package threads;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

/**
 * @author chouhan_r
 *
 */
public class Message {
    private String message;

    ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    ReentrantLock takelock = new ReentrantLock();
    private boolean empty =true;
    public  void put(String message){
        lock.lock();
        while(!empty){
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        empty = false;
        this.message = message;

        notifyAll();
        lock.unlock();
    }

    public String take(){

        takelock.lock();
        while(empty){
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        empty = true;

        notifyAll();
        takelock.unlock();
        return message;

    }


}


/**
 * Producer.java
 */
package threads;

import java.util.Random;

public class Producer implements Runnable{
    private Message message;
    public Producer(Message message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String[] impInfo = {"Hello", "I am here", "why are you doing this ??", "No problem" };
        Random random = new Random();
        for(String str : impInfo){
            message.put(str);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(3000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        message.put("Finished");

    }



}

/**
 * Consumer.java
 */
package threads;

public class Consumer implements Runnable{
    private Message message;
    public Consumer(Message message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(message);
        String msg = message.take();
        while(!"Finished".equalsIgnoreCase(msg)){
            System.out.println(msg);
            msg = message.take();
        }


    }


}
```

=====================

```
/**
 * Main Program
 */
package threads;

public class ProConsTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Message message = new Message();
        new Thread(new Consumer(message)).start();
        new Thread(new Producer(message)).start();



    }

}
```

I am trying to execute this code using ReentrantLock but it is giving me followin error -

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at threads.Message.take(Message.java:39)
    at threads.Consumer.run(Consumer.java:11)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)
    at threads.Message.put(Message.java:31)
    at threads.Producer.run(Producer.java:16)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Am I doing something wrong here ?? when I mark methods in Message.java as synchronized it works perfect. Can we run this code only with the Reentrant lock ??

Comment: That's because `wait()` and `notify()` require you to own the object monitor, i.e. synchronize on whatever you're calling them on.

Comment: @Kayaman Can it be done with Reentrant lock ??

Comment: I read in a blog that " ReentrantLock provides same visibility and orderings guaranteed as implicit lock, acquired by synchronized keyword in Java" So I am trying do this without Synchronized method or any Synchronized block. Is it possible ??

Comment: It is not duplicate question @Kayaman, here I dont want to use the synchronize block or synchronize method, I want to run this using locks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Object.wait` and `Object.notify` are connected to the intrinsic locking feature, which is used with `synchronized` blocks and methods.

If you want to use `Lock`s, you can’t use these two methods. Instead you have to [create a `Condition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#newCondition()) and call [`await()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await()) on it, which should be paired with another thread calling [`signal()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#signal()) on the same `Condition` instance. Note that unlike `Object.wait` and `Object.notify`, you can have more than one `Condition` per `Lock` and threads waiting for a particular condition will be woken up by threads calling `signal` *on the same* `Condition` instance.

However, as with the intrinsic locking feature, you must own the associated lock before calling a method on a `Condition`. In case of a `ReadWriteLock`, you must own the write lock.

Unfortunately, `Condition`s inherit the methods `wait` and `notify` from `Object`, so it’s important to never mix them up, which requires special care due to the hard to distinguish names, `wait` and `await`.

The [documentation of `Condition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) contains a complete example. I just pick up one code fragment illustrating the usage in the `put` method:

> ```
> final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
> final Condition notFull  = lock.newCondition(); 
> final Condition notEmpty = lock.newCondition();
> ```
>
> …
>
> ```
> lock.lock();
> try {
>   while (count == items.length)
>     notFull.await();
>   items[putptr] = x;
>   if (++putptr == items.length) putptr = 0;
>   ++count;
>   notEmpty.signal();
> } finally {
>   lock.unlock();
> }
> ```